# Do I need a server for hosting website?

Tags: server, webserver

Is it possible to create my own web host service in an Ubuntu computer/server?
If so, how can I do it?

I'm really interested in making my own web host "company", even when the only web page is hosted in the server is my own web page. How can I do it?

I don't have any knowledge is networks or advance computer systems. I'm about to enter college but this could be perfect to start a new project.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/web-servers.html

Comment: If you need to ask this, then do you feel that you are ready to offer such services to paying customers? Why would a customer pick what you are offering as opposed to some other company's? (You don't need to answer this here, because it's largely unrelated to the question that you are asking here and now, but you really should think about these questions.)

Answer (score 5):

Addressing just the part about hosting your own web page:

Setting up a web server is actually pretty easy.  Setting up a *secure* web server is quite a bit more difficult.  If you want to get your feet wet, Digital Ocean has some really good tutorials.  [Here's the one for setting up an Apache web server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps). If you get interested and want to continue on, they have good tutorials about adding security as well.

If you want to host other people's web pages as well, that, also, is another level of difficulty.

Comment: Although the title is primarily a "yes/no" question, the OP actually asks "how can I do it?". It would be nice if you could sum up the main points in the link you provided inside the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up any unix-based computer as a webserver is very easy - Apache on unix runs over half the world's websites. Configuration interfaces range from the command line to Apple's Server application.

But that's just one link in the chain. People have to reach your website for it to be useful beyond your desk.

> I don't have any knowledge is networks or advance computer systems

That's a problem. you will need knowledge of networking, co-operation from your internet service provider (doesn't need to be active co-operation, they basically have to not block it), A DNS setup that allows for a changing IP address and a few other things.

Or you can pay someone to do all that for you. The webhosting market is huge, prices range from $1 / month / site and up, depending on your needs. Start there to get the basics under control, then later work on running it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have limited experience, you are better off with a server that has been setup by professionals like [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp) or [TurnKey](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack). They have done the engineering for you. Follow the directions they provide.

But while you are still learning, I suggest you would be better off as a *reseller* for a hosting company such as [Host Gator](http://www.hostgator.com/resellers) or [Dreamhost](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Reselling), and many [others](https://www.google.com/#&q=web+host+reseller).